# Autofac DependencyResolver of same service with 2 different services

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, dependency-resolver

I have one service with two different components

```
<component type="ConcreteA, ConcreteA" service="Interface, Interface" />
<component type="ConcreteB, ConcreteB" service="Interface, Interface" />
```

I want to resolve both. I am trying in this way

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader());
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

this._container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(this._container));
```

Now in my controller I want to resolve my dependency

```
public Interface _myInterface { get; set; }
```

And I use it in this way:

```
_myInterface.DoWork();
```

If I declare in the config just one component everything works perfectly. But If I add more component of the same Interface type, something goes wrong.
I have tried to replace the declaration of the property with

```
public List<Interface> _myInterfaces { get; set; }
```

But the property remain always null... How can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with

```
public Interface[] _myInterfaces { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public List<Interface> _myInterfaces { get; set; }
```